# Create a third list out of a list of indexes and a list of strings

Tags: python, list

This is probably a basic question, but I am not even sure how to formulate it properly.

I have two lists:

```
>>> indexes
array([0, 2, 3, ..., 8, 5, 7]) # choices are between 0 and 8

>>> colors
['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'black', 'purple', 'yellow', 'grey', 'magenta']
```

I want to do something less verbose and more pythonic than this:

```
color_labels = []
for i in range(len(indexes)):
    color_labels.append(colors[indexes[i]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since one of your lists is already a `numpy` array you can use `numpy's` fancy indexing

```
color_labels = np.array(colors)[indexes]
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
color_labels = [colors[i] for i in indexes]
```

This uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

You can do other cool things with comprehensions! If you use parens `()` instead of square brackets, you get a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), which is like a list comprehension except it gets lazily evaluated. And if you use curly braces `{}` and a colon `:` you get a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), which lets you quickly convert lists of tuples etc. into dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

z0r's answer using list comprehension is for sure the most readable.

However you can also use the [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
color_labels = map(colors.__getitem__, indexes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or `lambda`:

```
print map(lambda x: colors[x], indexes)
```